# Wanna be able to use property from child OR parent component (both ways) in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Well... I've got a few components each containing one specific 'Table' component. I have a default `settings` property in Table component that looks like:

```
export class MyTable implements OnInit {
  @Input() settings: any;

  /**
   * code, code, code...
   */

  ngOnInit() {
    this.settings = {
      limitOptions: [ 5, 10, 50, 100, 250 ],
      total: 0,
      sortBy: this._params.sort || this._DEFAULT_SORT,

      /**
       * more settings...
       */
    };
```

In all parent components I use table as follows:

---

HTML:

```
<my-table [settings]='settings'
          /* more attributes */>
</my-table>
```

TS:

```
public settings: {
  limitOptions: number[],
  total: number,
  sortBy: string,
  /* more... */
};
```

**ALL WORKS FINE**. But I need improvement and I just don't get the idea how to achieve that. Now I can only use this default `settings` from child component Table, **but I wanna have the ability** to use it from the parent component itself. So, if I have `this.settings = { ... }` in parent I wanna use it, if not - I wanna use default settings from TableComponent.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value in constructor. And then skip settings property in template:

```
<my-table></my-table>
```

my-table.component.ts:

```
export class MyTable implements OnInit {
  @Input() settings: any = {
      limitOptions: [ 5, 10, 50, 100, 250 ],
      total: 0,
      sortBy: this._params.sort || this._DEFAULT_SORT,

      /**
       * more settings...
       */
    };
```